# How can I Increase Memory of Beaglebone Black?

Tags: sd-card, beagleboneblack

everyone. I have been trying to increase the memory of my BleagleBone Black rev c without success.

I have followed these [instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OisHW.png) in order to increase the memory of my BBB with a 16GB microSD card. I have already tried burning 2 different images **Debian 9.1 2017-08-31 4GB SD LXQT** and **Debian 8.7 2017-03-19 4GB SD LXQT (without flashing the eMMc)** .

The steps that I have been using are listed below.

1. What I first did was to burn the image into the microSD card using
   [Etcher](https://etcher.io/).
2. Then I inserted the microSD into the BBB, I pushed the boot button
   and then I plugged it into my computer to turn it on.
3. After that, I logged into my BBB using ssh and I checked for the
   Debian version and it was correct. Indicating that the boot from the
   microSD card was correct, but when I tried to check disk space I
   couldn´t find the partition for the microSD.

[image]

As you can see in the image below it is supposed to show the rootfs where I have the new BBB image and the 16GB extra space, but I´m not able to see the extra partition. Does anyone know what I could be possibly doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am facing with the same issue and I end up with

1. Login to your BBB by ssh
2. Run this command
   `nano grow_partition.sh`
3. copy code from [here](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/blob/master/tools/grow_partition.sh) then paste it on the terminal
4. save file by pressing `control + o` then `enter`
5. Exit from nano editor by pressing  `control` + `x`
6. Run this command `sudo ./grow_partition.sh`
7. Reboot BBB

Enjoy :)

Comment: If you can't run the sudo ./grow_partition.sh, try to add x mode by run this command chmod +x ./grow_partitition

Comment: Note that the file linked above is the same file found in `/opt/scripts/tools/grow_partition.sh`, so you could just run that.

Answer (score 3):

I have a beaglebone black (original with 512MB mem) and I was able to use a different method to add swap memory successfully (unfortunately user3680704's method didn't work for me).

I got the idea from [this post](https://www.2daygeek.com/add-extend-increase-swap-space-memory-file-partition-linux/) which basically says the following:

You can check your current memory with

```
free -h
```

And you can create the swap memory by running these commands. Again a more detailed better explanation is in the link above, but in case that ever goes dead you can follow these:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
ls -lh /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Next open the fstab file by running

```
vi /etc/fstab
```

and add the following line to the file

```
/swapfile  swap  swap  defaults  0 0
```

You can then check your swap by running
    swapon --show

This worked well for me, added 1G of swap. You can add more or less by changing the 1G value